# Is dojo able to get all of events in whole page?

Tags: javascript, dojo

There is some code doing like this **sequentially:**

1. dojo set value for one widget and trigger the onchange event.
2. dojo.connect to onchange event of widget aforementioned.

Originally, I don't think the event of the 1st step will be caught by event handler setting up in step 2. However, looks like my assumption is wrong.

So my idea it try to get all of events before dojo.connect and kill all of them, then dojo.connect won't be able to make event handler catch previous occurred events.

Is it possible that something like dojo.stopAllEvent? After doing that, my dojo.connect code will correctly ignore the unnecessary events.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the answer to the title question, I thought I'd chime in on the onChange oddity.

I would have assumed the same thing as you, but it turns out that when you set the value of a form widget, the `onChange` event is fired with a timeout. From `dijit.form._FormWidget`:

```
// setTimout allows hidden value processing to run and
// also the onChange handler can safely adjust focus, etc
this._onChangeHandle = setTimeout(dojo.hitch(this,
    function(){
        this._onChangeHandle = null;
    this.onChange(newValue);
    }), 0); // try to collapse multiple onChange's fired faster than can be processed
```

This means that your step 2 proceeds and attaches the second `onChange` listener *before* the event actually triggers. What you can do to possibly solve your problem, is to use the `set` method's third argument.

```
yourFormWidget.set("value", myNewValue, false);
```

The third argument is called priorityChange, and when set to false the onChange event will not be triggered. Hope that helps. (Thanks to kgf on #dojo for teaching me :-) )

Comment: Thank you. You've really been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your actual question is simply how to avoid "hearing" the changes from your `set` calls before connecting the event, then one potential answer essentially lies within what I told Frode which he relayed earlier.

`dijit.form._FormWidget` fires `onChange` via a timeout, which essentially ensures that it actually fires only after the current function chain finishes executing.  Therefore, currently your `connect` ends up actually "winning" the race against the `onChange` firing, which you don't want.  You should, however, be able to force it to "lose" by also performing your actual connection within a timeout similarly.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/kfranqueiro/ur8tf/

Of course, if Frode's suggestion suffices for your purposes, it's potentially easier on the eyes.

Comment: Thank you. You've really been helpful.